# C# i need my program to launch as administrator the first time than after that as a usual user

Tags: c#, admin

Hi i am currently writing a program for a project and i have created an installer using the C# visual studio tools but when it installs my database it only has read rights and i cannot edit it. I have used the following code to change the rights but it only works if i launch it as an administrator.

```
DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Program Files\Group 27\Bookstore Bargainers\new itrw225 data1.mdb");
        DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
        dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("everyone", FileSystemRights.FullControl,
                                                         InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit,
                                                         PropagationFlags.NoPropagateInherit, AccessControlType.Allow));
        dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
```

What i wish to do is to run the programa automatically as an administrator one time and then switch to a normal user. How would i accomplish this. I tried using the manifests but i cannot seem to edit it in code.

Comment: Your database should be in the AppData folder, not program files.

Comment: Not sure how to do that.

Comment: Use something like `Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolders.AppData), "Group 27", "Bookstore Bargainers", "new itw225 data1.mdb")`

Comment: You do *NOT* want to change rights to anything in Program Files. It's not yours to change. It belongs to Windows, and granting access to it is a security leak. Put your database in the proper location and you won't have this issue. There are many existing posts here about where to put data that needs to be editable by the user.

Comment: My mistake. jeez

Answer (score 1):

The `Program Files` folder is no longer the correct place to put your database, and hasn't been for nearly two decades. Use this C# expression to get a better location, where non-privileged users already have write permissions:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)
```

Your installer can put a default instance of the database in the Program Files folder for your app, but the app should only copy the database to the special All Users Application Data folder if it can't find one there already, and that only requires the normal read permissions.

Comment: Thank you this is my first time using an installer so i was unsure how else to do it but thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you need more than one user on the machine to be able to access the database, then editing permissions on installed files is absolutely a job for the installation program and not the application.  Apps shouldn't modify permissions for themselves.

If you don't need more than one user, then Ron speaks the truth.  Have the application and it's database install into AppData.

If the installation method you are using doesn't give you the ability to modify permissions or install to AppData (like MSI/WiX do), then you need a more powerful installer.

Comment: The application can still be installed in program files, the read/write data should go in AppData.

Comment: There is also an `All Users Application Data` folder. Even installation programs shouldn't modify permissions within Program Files anymore.